# How to collect string fields from lookup documents into an array field of root documents in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

> Sample Data Set

There is this first set of documents *SET A*:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("56b872f475a4b3000326080e"),
"docId" : "123456",
"baseId" : "123-123-123-123",
"name" : "test for 1",
"category" : "default"
}

{"_id" : ObjectId("56b872f475a4b3000326080e"),
"docId" : "123456",
"baseId" : "124-124-124-124",
"name" : "test for 2",
"category" : "default"}
```

And there is a second set of documents *SET B* which have a many to one relationship with the **docId** key of *SET A* documents

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("56b872f475a4b3000326080e"),
"docId" : "123456",
"collect" : "abcd",
"name" : "test for date format"}

{"_id" : ObjectId("56b872f475a4b3000326080e"),
"docId" : "123456",
"collect" : "bcde",
"name" : "test for date format"}

{"_id" : ObjectId("56b872f475a4b3000326080e"),
"docId" : "123457",
"collect" : "abcd",
"name" : "test for date format"}

{"_id" : ObjectId("56b872f475a4b3000326080e"),
"docId" : "123457",
"collect" : "bcdef",
"name" : "test for date format",}
```

Need the resulting documents to be *SET A* documents with extra field aggregates from *SET B* documents where the **collect** key from all the SET B documents should get added to an array field on the resulting document

Eg: The resulting documents should push (distinct) the ***collect*** key values from each *SET B* documents matching the ***docId*** into ***collectArray***

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("56b872f475a4b3000326080e"),
"docId" : "123456",
"baseId" : "123-123-123-123",
"name" : "test for 1",
"category" : "default"
"collectArray" : ["abcd", "bcde"]
}

{"_id" : ObjectId("56b872f475a4b3000326080e"),
"docId" : "123457",
"baseId" : "124-124-124-124",
"name" : "test for 2",
"category" : "default"
"collectArray" : ["abcd", "bcdef"]
}
```

> Tried Approaches with the lookup:

```
 {
    $lookup: {
        from: "set2collection",
        localField: "docId",
        foreignField: "docId",
        as: "lookups"
    }
}
```

1. $addToSet (Error : Only available with $group)
2. $addToField (Couldn't find an operator to collect distinct values)
3. $mergeToObject (Error : Unary operator when used as an accumulator)

> Reason of exploration

The existing logic is done via first grouping all the *SET B* documents by the **docId** and then applying $addToSet which is turning out to be very slow as the count of documents in *SET B* is very high. 
Need to optimize the same which is why thought of trying lookup.

Please help and suggest with either the current approach or if any other route should be taken for the same.

Comment: This adds duplicates to the array @Ashh. Need a way to push distinct values to the array.

Comment: Use `$setUnion`. https://mongoplayground.net/p/CuSg1vokJJ6